# sbrk and malloc in c

Tags: c, malloc, sbrk

I have following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main () {
        void *result[20];
        void *endptr;
        void *x;
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                result[i] = malloc(10);
                printf("111 : %d\n",result[i]);
        }
        endptr= sbrk(0);
        printf("\n222 : %d\n",endptr);
        x = malloc(60); ----------- error
        return 0;
}
```

I want to print numeric value of all the void pointers and the count how many times sbrk function called form malloc?

If I print *endptr in printf statement it gives me error. Currently I think it prints address where memory is allocated. %x would just convert current value in hex and print right?

x = malloc(60) also gives error :  void value not ignored as it ought to be
How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: printf("\n222 : %d\n",(int)endptr);  should work.

Comment: You want the integer value of the pointer address, right?

Comment: If I have *ptr ; // do not consider the syntax
*ptr = 3;
then printf(*ptr,ptr) will print 3 and address of ptr and want *ptr

Comment: I don't understand.  In your example, *ptr is 3.

Comment: `printf(*ptr,ptr)`: Only valid if `ptr` is of type `char**` and points to a `char*` pointing to a valid format string using up to one format specifier, which must be `%p`.

Comment: Use `printf("\n222 : %p\n", endptr);`

Answer (score 2):

sbrk(0) returns the current size of the "program break", which isn't actually a pointer, so dereferencing it will give an error.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbrk

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/brk.html

Comment: As your links show, `sbrk(0)` returns the current break (not a size) which IS a pointer.  As it points to one byte past the end of usable memory, dereferencing it will pretty much always give an error.

Comment: @chux: In the comment "If I print *endptr in printf it gives me error"

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to print data pointers in C using printf is this (there is no format for code pointers):

```
printf("%p", pointer);
```

That should output the pointer in the best format for the platform, and can be read back by `scanf`.
Using any other format specifier for pointers is explicitly **Undefined Behavior**, anything may happen.

Also, there is no guarantee `malloc()` uses legacy `sbrk()` at all. And even if it does, it might be able to use available free blocks instead of having to call it. Next, there is no guarantee `sbrk()` points to valid storage, so dereferencing it is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Note: I think printing code pointers is well defined with `printf("%p", (void*) code_pointer);`

Comment: @chux: The conversion is not guaranteed.

Comment: C11 spec J.5.7 says "A pointer to a function may be cast to a pointer to an object or to void, allowing a function to be inspected ...", but as you point out 'The conversion is not guaranteed" being in the _Informative_ section.

Comment: @chux: Actually, it is worse. That section lists **common extensions**. Kudos for checking.